# How to make program run after clicking the button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I`ve a problem that the program does not start after clicking the start button, but when the tkinter window is closed it starts. How can I make it working right after the button is clicked? Thought it could be because it writes it in a txt file, but shell print does not work eather.

---

```
from turtle import color
import time
import psutil
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()             
 
# Open window having dimension 900x600 and red colour
root.geometry('900x600')
root.configure(bg='black')
# ints for monitoring
last_received = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_recv
last_sent = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_sent
last_total = last_received + last_sent
running = False
a=1

#Define a function to start the programm
def start_monitorting():
        global running
        running = True
        

def stop_monitorting():
    global running
    running = False
    

# Create a Button
start_button = Button(root, text = 'Start Monitoring',height=5, width=50, fg='red', bg='grey',
                          command = start_monitorting)
stop_button = Button(root, text = 'Start Monitoring',height=a, width=50, fg='red', bg='grey',
                          command = stop_monitorting)
#where it will be 
start_button.pack(side = 'bottom')    
root.mainloop()   

#traffic monitoring loop
while running:
   
    bytes_received = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_recv
    bytes_sent = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_sent
    bytes_total = bytes_received + bytes_sent

    new_receievd = bytes_received - last_received
    new_sent = bytes_sent - last_sent
    new_total = bytes_total - last_total

    mb_new_received = new_receievd / 1024 / 1024
    mb_new_sent = new_sent / 1024 /1024
    mb_new_total = new_total / 1024 / 1024
    
    #we will print it into the txt file so we can log it and open on a GUI
    with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
        print(f"{mb_new_received:.2f} MB received, {mb_new_sent:.2f} MB sent, {mb_new_sent:.2f} MB total", file=f)
    last_received = bytes_received
    last_sent = bytes_sent
    last_total = bytes_total 
    f.close()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

According To Python, **2 Loops Can NOT Run Simultaneously!**

And There is Already a Loop Running - `root.mainloop()` (This Means The GUI is Running Continuously, It wont end)

So, As the Rule The Under The Loop - `while running:` Cant Run!

Now Why Does The `while running:` Starts When The Window is Closed?

It Starts Because `root.mainloop()` Is **Manually Ended** By You So The Code Can Continue to The Other Loop!

**Solution:**

```
- Make a Function Where You Would Put Your Code Your want to Run
(I am Not Using Your Code Here, I actually Know Nothing About psutil But Its Not The Case!)

- Put Your Conditionals If You want, else  Put Your Code in The Function

- Now, As in your Case, Run the Function By `FunctionName()` in The `start_monitorting` Function
```

My Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry('900x600')
root.configure(bg='black')
def main():
  if running:
    print("For Checking")
    #Your Code  
running = False
a = 1


def start_monitorting():
    global running
    running = True
    main()


def stop_monitorting():
    global running
    running = False

start_button = Button(root, text='Start Monitoring', height=5, width=50, fg='red', bg='grey',
                      command=start_monitorting)
stop_button = Button(root, text='Start Monitoring', height=a, width=50, fg='red', bg='grey',
                     command=stop_monitorting)

start_button.pack(side='bottom')



root.mainloop()
```

Hope This Helped You!

Comment: If it didn't help him, this sure helped me! Thanks

Comment: oh, i am pleased to hear that!